# jQuery selection with dynamic id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that is dynamically generated, and has dynamically generated id's (and potentially classes). The forms are the same but they have the related id tacked on to the end.

How can I select each set of inputs and apply code to each one?

I was experimenting with $('input[id^=@id_airline_for_]') but could not get it to fly. I suspect I am missing some fundamental jQuery knowledge that is holding me back since I am sure this is a common problem with dynamic forms.

```
<form method='POST'>
    <label for="id_airline_for_8">Airline</label>:
    <input id="id_airline_for_8" class="arrival_transfer_toggle_8" type="text" maxlength="30" name="airline_for_8"/>
    <label for="id_flight_number_for_8">Flight Number</label>:
    <input id="id_flight_number_for_8" class="arrival_transfer_toggle_8" type="text" maxlength="30" name="flight_number_for_8"/>

    <label for="id_airline_for_17">Airline</label>:
    <input id="id_airline_for_17" class="arrival_transfer_toggle_17" type="text" maxlength="30" name="airline_for_17"/>
    <label for="id_flight_number_for_17">Flight Number</label>:
    <input id="id_flight_number_for_17" class="arrival_transfer_toggle_17" type="text" maxlength="30" name="flight_number_for_17"/>

    -- snip --

</form>
```

EDIT: I should update that i want to be able to perform some action when the input is clicked but only for classes with a matching id at the end.

To make it easy, lets say I want all inputs with a matching id at the end of the #id to disappear when one is clicked (just for arguments sake).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
$("input[id^='id_airline_for_']").each(function() {
  var id = parseInt(this.id.replace("id_airline_for_", ""), 10);
  var airline = $("#id_airline_for_" + id);
  var flightNumber = $("#id_flight_number_for_" + id);
  // do stuff with airline and flightNumber <input>s
});
```

Comment: I think this might get me to the point where I can get what I want. I will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: To improve on this. How would I deal with events? If say someone clicks the id_flight_number_for_17 input how can I create an event call back just for that particular 'set' of inputs or actually, to make it an easier problem, how would I go about defining a general event callback just for that input

Comment: Are you capable of changing the outputted HTML code? If so, I'd recommend a reorganization of your HTML structure.

Comment: @Ben, I couldn't get this work unless I added a second parameter to replace(). I've taken the liberty of editing this into your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$("input#id_airline_for" + id)` (where `id` is your number, e.g., 8), but it will be faster if you drop the tag name and just use:

```
$("#id_airline_for" + id);
```

Comment: I don't have access to a javascript id variable.

Comment: This really did the work for me. thanks @Ben Alpert.

Answer (score 2):

The following will get you all of the inputs that contain `id_airline_for` in their name.

```
$("input[id^='id_airline_for']")
```

If you need to do this on a per form basis, you'll want to give each form its own ID and select them in groups that way.

```
$("#formJetBlue input[id^='id_airline_for']")
$("#formNwa input[id^='id_airline_for']")
$("#formOceanic input[id^='id_airline_for']")
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should be using the @ sign and you're missing some quotes:

Instead of this:
$('input[id^=@id_airline_for_]')

try this:
$("input[id^='id_airline_for_']")

See this, too:

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue

Answer (score 0):

Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring

```
$('input[id *= id_airline_for]').attr('checked', headerChecked);
```

it will select all elements that contain 'id_airline_for' string in the 'id' attribute