# expanding div - only want the clicked div to expand in php echo

Tags: jquery, html, echo

I have results echo'ed from a database, i have included jquery expand code to expand the div when the title is clicked, however currently when a title of one result is clicked, all of the other echo'ed divs expand.

Could someone help me to make it so that only the clicked div expands. Thankyou for any help or advice!

this is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".expanderHead").click(function(){
    $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
    if ($("#expanderSign").text() == "+"){
        $("#expanderSign").html("−")
    }
    else {
        $("#expanderSign").text("+")
    }
});
});
</script>
```

this is the echo statement:

```
    echo "<table width='50%' style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<div id='page-wrap'>";
echo "<div class='discounted-item freeshipping'>";

echo "<a href='./img/users/" . $row['category'] . "/" . $row['username'] . "/" . $row['filename'] . "' rel='lightbox'><img src=\"./img/users/" . $row['category'] . "/" . $row['username'] . "/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" width='15%' height='80%' /></a>";


echo "<div id='expanderHead'>";
echo "<div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title' style='width: 70%;'>" .$row['fname'] . "</div><div class='reason' style='width: 29%;'><b>". $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['surname'] ."</b></div></div>";


echo "<div id='expanderContent' style='display:none'><div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title1' style='width: 70%;'>" . $row['lname'] . "</div><div class='reason1' style='width: 29%;'>Category:<br /> ". $row['category'] . "</div></div></div>";

echo "<div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title2' style='width: 70%;'><a href='#' data-reveal-id='myModal".$count."'>Click here For more info</a></div><div class='reason2' style='width: 29%;'>Price: &pound;". $row['price'] . "</div></div>";


echo "</div>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: thankyou for your reply, could you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Don't post your PHP code, post what the PHP code generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using $(this) inside to only find elements relative to the current clicked

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".expanderHead").click(function(){
        var $exsign = $("#expanderSign");
        $(this).find("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
        $exsign.html($exsign.text() == '+' ? '-': '+');   
        // simplify your if/else into one line using ternary operator
        // if  $exsign.text() == "+" then use "-" else "+"
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

probably because you are expanding the whole `.class` instead of the unique `#id` of the clicked `div`.

about your comment

> okay thankyou for clearing this up, do you know how i could add a
>   count function in to the div id name so that it would work?

see if this can help you:

dynamic id with php
http://perishablepress.com/dynamic-body-class-id-php-wordpress/

dynamic id with jquery
[jQuery selection with dynamic id's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408265/jquery-selection-with-dynamic-ids)

Comment: thankyou for your reply, this works, but now only the first results div expands, any ideas on how i can get the specific div which is clicked to expand? using a count function or some sort?

Comment: dont forget that `#id` is unique. you can not have two elements (ex: div) `#expanderSign`. a `.class` , on the other hand, can be assigned to several elements. if you are echoing this line `echo "<div id='expanderHead'>";` multiple times, could have a problem.

Comment: okay thankyou for clearing this up, do you know how i could add a count function in to the div id name so that it would work?