# Hide only click div from echoed php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, echo

Before asking this, I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569967/expanding-div-only-want-the-clicked-div-to-expand-in-php-echo)

I am very new to `php` and `JavaScript`. But the problem here is I `echo` results from my database with `divs` example below.

```
echo "<div class="togBtn"><div class="result">$results</div></div>";
```

And the `html` output is something like

```
<div class="togBtn"><div class="result">firstresult</div></div>
<div class="togBtn"><div class="result">secondresult</div></div>
```

But i then wrote a `JavaScript` that toggles `.result` when `.togBtn` is `click`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".togBtn").click(function() {
        $(".result").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

But the problem is that when i `click` the `.togBtn`, both the `div` with firstresult and secondresult is `toggled`. My question is, is it possible that when i `click` `.togBtn` only that `div` results is toggled rather than both `echoed` results. Am echoing the results wrongly such that it causes the problem. Any suggestion would do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats because you have lots of classes called `ad_user_info` You are not being specific enough

Comment: I know that's the reason but i can't write multiple classes since i am get the data from database. Is there a way i can click on and only that one toggles?

Comment: Have you tried assigning an ID to specific div and call it.

Comment: I am echoing my `php` results with those `divs`. The data amount can change. I don't think assigning `id` to each `div` is the best solution but thanks @jmag for your help

Comment: We **cannot possibly** give you a solution as we have **no knowlede** of the rest of the code involved in producing this page!

Comment: Any reason you don't think assigning ID's are a good solution? You can auto generate ID's if you're creating your divs in a loop.

Comment: There is only one element with class `posted_by` to which `click` event listener is attached to. Upon click you are hiding all elements with class `ad_info_conn_btn`. How to know which particular element with class `ad_info_conn_btn` you want to hide.

Comment: If you only want to toggle element with class `ad_info_conn_btn` upon click then attach the event listener to it instead of `posted_by`

Comment: The thing is i have about 1000 data being echoed with those `div` from database but when i click on 1 `.posted_by`, all the 1000 `.ad_user_info` `slideToggle`. Is it possible i click on `.posted_by ` and the `ad_user_info` of that 1 `slideToggle`. I have edited the `php` code. Thanks in advance. Hope you guys understand now? PS: if you check the link in my question, you might understand what i am asking for

Comment: Thank you all. Finally solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use the `jQuery .next() .prev()` with `$(this)`

```
$('.togBtn').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```