# jQuery dynamic change with DOM updation

Tags: jquery

I have inputs in a form like below. The number in the `id/name` is the sequence number. The sequence of inputs may be **decreased/increased** **dynamically** through jQuery. There is a default number of inputs in the form which will always be an Integer greater than 0.

```
<select name="r_details-0-ch" id="id_r_details-0-ch"><option value="" selected="">-</option>
<input type="text" name="r_details-0-amt" step="0.01" id="id_r_details-0-amt">
<input type="text" name="r_details-0-nar" class="vTextField" maxlength="100" id="id_r_details-0-nar">


<select name="r_details-0-ch" id="id_r_details-0-ch"><option value="" selected="">-</option> 
<input type="text" name="r_details-1-amt" step="0.01" id="id_r_details-1-amt">
<input type="text" name="r_details-1-nar" class="vTextField" maxlength="100" id="id_r_details-1-nar">
```

I want to update `id_r_details-{x}-nar` via Ajax on change on of `id_r_details-{x}-amt` where `x` is a number representing the sequence.

Just for information the form is rendered by `Django Admin inlines`.

My questions:

1. How to assign `.on('change', )` to `id_r_details-{x}-amt`.
2. How to then update id_r_details-{x}-nar`with return value`
3. The value of the specific `id_r_details_{x}_ch` needs to be passed to the Ajax call.
   Ch is a select input with options, which I have omitted here for clarity.

EDIT: Need to identify the sequence which fires .on('change, ). Then I think I can do all that needs to be done.

Comment: There are so many examples of this, here's the first one searching for "[jQuery dynamic id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408265/jquery-selection-with-dynamic-ids)". Pls try searching before opening duplicate questions.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching with sequence. The search was bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the on change function as given below. It will assign onchange to the id's whose are starting with **id_r_details**

```
$('[id^=id_r_details]').on('change', function() {
   console.log(this);
  // segretgate the your functionality using if condition
  // do something here
});
```

Comment: How to identity the sequence which will fire the .on(change

Comment: the clicked id is available in `this.id`. as i consoled this object that will return clicked element details.

Comment: Yes, but can we extract the sequence number from it, needed to access other input/select

Comment: No you have to extract different conditions using if condition according to the ID's.